# Linux POSIX C LibPCRE `double free or corruption (fasttop)` crash

Tags: c, linux, pcre, glibc

I have the following code (it reads a process virtual memory and matches some strings using libpcre), it compiles without errors but if I compile it with `-Wall` I get some warnings I will show after the code.

The compiled code runs but crashes with `*** glibc detected *** ./readmempcreuniq: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x097b9c80 ***`, I suspect the problem is on the line `pcre_get_substring(page, vector, pairs, 0, &buff);` because the first argument of the function expects `'const char *'` but gets `'unsigned char *'`, how can I make it right?

```
#ifdef TARGET_64
// for 64bit target (see /proc/cpuinfo addr size virtual)
#define MEM_MAX (1ULL << 48)
#else
#define MEM_MAX (1ULL << 32)
#endif

#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <pcre.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <pid>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    char buf[128];
    int pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "/proc/%d/mem", pid);
    int fd = open(buf, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening mem file: %m\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    pcre *f;
    pcre_extra *f_ext;
    char *pattern = "([0-9]{20,22})";
    const char *errstr;
    int errchar;
    int vector[50];
    int vecsize = 50;
    int pairs;
    const char *buff;
    const unsigned char *tables;
    int a;
    int count = 0;
    const char **matches = NULL;
    const char **more_matches;

    char *loc = setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, loc);
    tables = pcre_maketables();

    long ptret = ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, 0, 0);
    if (ptret == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Ptrace failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        exit(1);
    }

    unsigned char page[4096];
    unsigned long long offset = 0;


    while (offset < MEM_MAX) {
        lseek64(fd, offset, SEEK_SET);

        ssize_t ret;
        ret = read(fd, page, sizeof(page));

        if (ret > 0) {
            page[ret] = '\0';
            if((f = pcre_compile(pattern, PCRE_CASELESS|PCRE_MULTILINE, &errstr, &errchar, tables)) == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error: %s\nCharacter N%i\nPattern:%s\n", errstr, errchar, pattern);
            }
            else
            {
                f_ext = pcre_study(f, 0, &errstr);
                a = 0;

                while((pairs = pcre_exec(f, f_ext, page, sizeof(page), a, PCRE_NOTEMPTY, vector, vecsize)) >=0)
                {
                    pcre_get_substring(page, vector, pairs, 0, &buff);
                    //printf("%s\n", buff);
                    more_matches = realloc(matches, (count+1)* sizeof(*more_matches));
                    if (more_matches!=NULL)
                    {
                        matches=more_matches;
                        matches[count++]=buff;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        free(matches);
                        puts("Error (re)allocating memory");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    a = vector[1] + 1;
                }
                int matches_len = count;
                const char *uniques[matches_len];
                int uniques_len = 0;
                int already_exists;
                int i, j;
                for (i = 0; i < matches_len; i++)
                {
                    already_exists = 0;
                    for ( j = 0; j < uniques_len; j++)
                    {
                        if (!strcmp(matches[i], uniques[j]))
                        {
                            already_exists = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!already_exists)
                    {
                        uniques[uniques_len] = matches[i];
                        uniques_len++;
                    }
                }
                for (i = 0; i < uniques_len; i++)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", uniques[i]);
                }
                free(matches);
                pcre_free(f);
            }

        }

        offset += sizeof(page);
    }

    ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, 0, 0);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

The error:

```
xtmtrx@server:~/regex/proc$ ./readmempcreuniq 5663
92991999918876543209
99299299292663552673
111992229922222288
119988922220000077
*** glibc detected *** ./readmempcreuniq: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x097b9c80 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6c0c1)[0xb7dfa0c1]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6d930)[0xb7dfb930]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x71681)[0xb7dff681]
/lib/libc.so.6(realloc+0xe3)[0xb7dffb13]
./readmempcreuniq[0x8048c86]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0xb7da4ce7]
./readmempcreuniq[0x80488b1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0804a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 68388533                           /root/regex/proc/readmempcreuniq
0804a000-0804b000 r--p 00001000 fd:01 68388533                           /root/regex/proc/readmempcreuniq
0804b000-0804c000 rw-p 00002000 fd:01 68388533                           /root/regex/proc/readmempcreuniq
097a1000-097c2000 rw-p 097a1000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
b7c00000-b7c21000 rw-p b7c00000 00:00 0
b7c21000-b7d00000 ---p b7c21000 00:00 0
b7d66000-b7d80000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 65901968                           /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b7d80000-b7d81000 r--p 00019000 fd:01 65901968                           /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b7d81000-b7d82000 rw-p 0001a000 fd:01 65901968                           /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b7d8c000-b7d8e000 rw-p b7d8c000 00:00 0
b7d8e000-b7ee5000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 65901949                           /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
b7ee5000-b7ee7000 r--p 00157000 fd:01 65901949                           /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
b7ee7000-b7ee8000 rw-p 00159000 fd:01 65901949                           /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
b7ee8000-b7eeb000 rw-p b7ee8000 00:00 0
b7eeb000-b7f1e000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 65901993                           /lib/libpcre.so.3.12.1
b7f1e000-b7f1f000 r--p 00032000 fd:01 65901993                           /lib/libpcre.so.3.12.1
b7f1f000-b7f20000 rw-p 00033000 fd:01 65901993                           /lib/libpcre.so.3.12.1
b7f29000-b7f2c000 rw-p b7f29000 00:00 0
b7f2c000-b7f48000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 65901940                           /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
b7f48000-b7f49000 r--p 0001b000 fd:01 65901940                           /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
b7f49000-b7f4a000 rw-p 0001c000 fd:01 65901940                           /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
bf8c1000-bf8d6000 rw-p 7ffffffe9000 00:00 0                              [stack]
Aborted
```

Warnings compiling the code with `-Wall` switch:

> xtmtrx@server:~/regex/proc$ gcc -o readmempcreuniq readmempcreuniq.c
>   -lpcre -Wall readmempcreuniq.c: In function 'main': readmempcreuniq.c:83: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 3
>   of 'pcre_exec' differ in signedness /usr/include/pcre.h:286: note:
>   expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'unsigned char *'
>   readmempcreuniq.c:85: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1
>   of 'pcre_get_substring' differ in signedness /usr/include/pcre.h:297:
>   note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'unsigned char
>   *'

EDIT:

As per @stdcall tip, I compiled the program with `efence` then used GDB on the core dump:

```
xtmtrx@server:~/regex/proc$ ./readmempcreuniq 6036

  Electric Fence 2.1 Copyright (C) 1987-1998 Bruce Perens.
5,
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
xtmtrx@server:~/regex/proc$ gdb ./readmempcreuniq core
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2-ubuntu
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /root/regex/proc/readmempcreuniq...done.
[New Thread 6093]
Reading symbols from /lib/libpcre.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libpcre.so.3
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libefence.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libefence.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/libc.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/libpthread.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libpthread.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/ld-linux.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/ld-linux.so.2
Core was generated by `./readmempcreuniq 6036'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x08048ef8 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbfe1d2d4) at readmempcreuniq.c:125
125                                                     uniques[uniques_len] = matches[i];
```

seems @alk is right that the problem resides in `uniques[uniques_len] = matches[i];`

NEW EDIT:

As per @alk tip, I've changed the line:

```
for ( j = 0; j < uniques_len; j++)
```

to:

```
for ( j = 0; j < matches_len; j++)
```

now the segfault is elsewhere:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x08048ea7 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbfaaa3e4) at readmempcreuniq.c:118
118                                                     if (!strcmp(matches[i], uniques[j]))
```

Comment: The warnings are harmless. Use an explicit cast to get rid of them, or just use `char` throughout in the first place.

Comment: I don't think I can use only `char` instead `unsigned char page[4096];` because of this I think I get error on line `pcre_get_substring(page, vector, pairs, 0, &buff);` because this function expects an `unsigned char *`

Comment: tables must be unsigned char, pages plain char.

Comment: On my machine `pcre_get_substring` expects plain char pointers. I cannot find anything different in online sources either.

Comment: So I should try to find another way with `pcre` than `pcre_get_substring` as I thought.

Comment: I would suggest checking out `efence`. it will caused SEGFAUT at the moment you overwrite your allocated memory. pin pointing exactly where the problem  lays.

Comment: I want to know how thats possible. debug-print `matches_len` prior to entering the loops, and `uniques_len` with each match-save (and check my post for a much simpler loop).

Comment: Changed my loop with yours, now the segfault is elsewhere `#0  0x08048eee in main ()`

Comment: @xtmtrx hope this is it: reset `count` to zero at the same time you `free` matches and set it to null.

Comment: @WhozCraig, if I reset the `count` to `0` there, the code runs without segfaulting but now no unique matches :)

Comment: What do you mean? The code as you have it should report a unique match set for each page before resetting and moving to the next. At least it better. Which reminds me. Are you trying to build a *cumulative* set of uniques across *all* pages ?

Comment: Look here what I get: http://pastebin.com/7a70ws77

Comment: Yes, WhozCraig, I want to build a `cumulative` set of uniques across `all` pages! So the final output after searching and matching everything my code would print out only unique matches.

Comment: Well no wonder, then. you shouldn't be freeing matches at all of that is the case. In doing so the next loop on the next page will realloc `count+1` space for entries, and begin populating the last one, but everything *below* that is filled with indeterminate values. I think your solution is to let matches reset as you are, but dynamically grow the uniques via realloc as well. and move it and its accumulated length to outer-most scope. You should also likely free the substring if it *was* a dupe rather than letting it leak.

Comment: But if I don't free matches I get the segfault... Any idea how to do it and maybe add to your answer so I accept it? Thanks for your REAL help!

Comment: ok. I''ll add one more thing, which is what I *think* you're trying to do, build a unique list of matches). Can't guarantee it will be perfect, as I don't know the API, but the algorithm in-general I do know (I think, anyway).

Comment: ok. its up. step that in a debugger and see where it takes you. Gotta get some sleep. take it easy, and best of luck to you.

Comment: now the code doesn't do anything. I'll find the problem. take a good sleep and thanks!

Comment: `page[ret] = '\0';` is a classic buffer overrun, if your read() call reads the entire `sizeof page` , you're one past your array

Comment: I already removed the '\0', has nothing to do with the segfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never reset `matches` to `NULL` after `free()`ing it before the next round in the loop. Consequently it still retains the original value after the first round of reallocs.

Either set it to `NULL` prior to entering the inner processing loop (redundant on the first pass), or set it *back* to `NULL` immediately after the `free(matches)`. Alternatively you could simply make it local to the encompassing scope of the next-outer loop with an initial `NULL` value as you have it, but the changes previously mentioned are the most minimal I can think of.

**Examples**

```
matches = NULL; // HERE
while((pairs = pcre_exec(f, f_ext, page, sizeof(page), a, PCRE_NOTEMPTY, vector, vecsize)) >=0)
{
        pcre_get_substring(page, vector, pairs, 0, &buff);
        //printf("%s\n", buff);
        more_matches = realloc(matches, (count+1)* sizeof(*more_matches));
        if (more_matches!=NULL)
        {
                matches=more_matches;
                matches[count++]=buff;
        }
        else
        {
                free(matches);
                puts("Error (re)allocating memory");
                exit(1);
        }
        a = vector[1] + 1;
}
```

Or....

```
for (i = 0; i < uniques_len; i++)
{
        printf("%s\n", uniques[i]);
}
free(matches);
matches = NULL; // or HERE
pcre_free(f);
```

---

**More Stuff**

Continuing down the path of things I've noticed:

This:

```
ssize_t ret;
ret = read(fd, page, sizeof(page));

if (ret > 0) {
        page[ret] = '\0';
```

appears to be trying to set a null char terminator. if so, you're invoking **undefined behavior** on a full-populated buffer. It should be this:

```
ssize_t ret = read(fd, page, sizeof(page)-1); // NOTE SPACE FOR TERM
if (ret > 0) {
        page[ret] = 0;
```

If the size of the buffer is specific (you chose 4K for a reason) it should be 4097 to ensure a max-exact 4K buffer.

---

**And another...**

You're reading the page, which I cannot claim is or is not requiring to be terminated as I showed in the code before. But assuming it is and you did I I suggested (or.. not), this also looks wrong:

```
while((pairs = pcre_exec(f, f_ext, page, sizeof(page), a, PCRE_NOTEMPTY, vector, vecsize)) >=0)
```

Here you're passing the size of the entire buffer; *not* the size of the actual data you read. I'm the first person to tell you I'm unfamiliar with the API, but I'm fairly sure this should be:

```
// notice the length of the buffer passed, ret
while((pairs = pcre_exec(f, f_ext, page, ret, a, PCRE_NOTEMPTY, vector, vecsize)) >=0)
```

In other words, on an undersized read you're telling it the data is longer than it really is. Again, I'm naive to their API, but this seems reasonable.

---

**Of Unique Matches...**

Hopefully easier to read.

```
int matches_len = count, uniques_len = 0;
int i = 0, j = 0;

const char *uniques[matches_len];
for (i=0; i < matches_len; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < uniques_len; ++j)
    {
        if (!strcmp(matches[i], uniques[j]))
            break;
    }

    if (j == uniques_len)
        uniques[uniques_len++] = matches[i];
}

for (i = 0; i < uniques_len; ++i)
    printf("%s\n", uniques[i]);
```

---

**Continuing on...**

Reset `count` to zero after each page. Right after the `free(matches); matches = NULL;` would be a good place.

Worth noting. you have no exit case in your outer loop once the file reads start failing, so there will be much slamming on the file that is unable to seek beyond its end. until you reach your limiter count.

---

**Final Thoughts**

I *think* this is close to what you're trying to do:

```
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <pcre.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // CHANGE TO ACCEPT PROC-ID FROM CMDLINE    
    int pid = 5916;

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

    const char *error = NULL;
    int erroffset = 0;
    const char **uniques = NULL;
    size_t uniques_len = 0;

    const char regex[] = "[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}";
    pcre* re = pcre_compile (regex,          /* the pattern */
                    PCRE_MULTILINE|PCRE_DOTALL|PCRE_NEWLINE_ANYCRLF,
                    &error,         /* for error message */
                    &erroffset,     /* for error offset */
                    0);             /* use default character tables */
    if (!re)
    {
        printf("pcre_compile failed (offset: %d), %s\n", erroffset, error);
        return -1;
    }

    // start proc trace
    long ptret = ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, 0, 0);
    if (ptret == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Ptrace failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    char path[256];
    snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "/proc/%d/maps", pid);
    FILE *maps = fopen(path, "r");
    snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "/proc/%d/mem", pid);
    int mem = open(path, O_RDONLY);

    if(maps && (mem != -1))
    {
        char buf[BUFSIZ + 1];
        while(fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, maps))
        {
            long long unsigned int start, end;
            if (sscanf(buf, "%llx-%llx", &start, &end) != 2)
                break;

            printf("reading %llx - %llx\n", start, end);

            lseek64(mem, start, SEEK_SET);
            while (start < end)
            {
                char page[4096] =  {0};
                int rd = read(mem, page, sizeof(page));
                if (rd < 0)
                    break;

                start += sizeof(page);

                int ov[128] = {0};
                unsigned int ov_len = 0;
                int rc = 0;

                while ((rc = pcre_exec(re, 0, page, (int)(rd), ov_len, 0, ov, 128)) >= 0)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    for(; i < rc; ++i)
                    {
                        const char *sp = NULL;
                        pcre_get_substring(page, ov, rc, i, &sp);

                        // search unique list
                        size_t j=0;
                        for (;j<uniques_len;++j)
                        {
                            if (!strcmp(sp, uniques[j]))
                            break;
                        }

                        if (uniques_len == j)
                        {
                            const char **tmp = realloc(uniques, (uniques_len+1)*sizeof(*uniques));
                            if (tmp == NULL)
                            {
                                perror("Failed to resize uniques.");
                                pcre_free_substring(sp);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                uniques = tmp;
                                uniques[uniques_len++] = sp;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {   // delete string. not needed
                            pcre_free_substring(sp);
                        }
                    }
                    ov_len = ov[2*(rc-1)]+1;
                }
            }
        }

        fclose(maps);
        close(mem);
    }

    size_t n = 0;
    for (; n<uniques_len; ++n)
    {
        printf("%s\n", uniques[n]);
        pcre_free_substring(uniques[n]);
    }
    printf("total uniques: %lu\n", uniques_len);
    free(uniques);

    ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Caveat. I know *zero* about this API, but what I've seen here and briefly reviewed online. YMMV UAYOR. but it seems to be you had it all along. Just accumulate uniques independent of pages (which I think will still be a problem, page boundaries, but thats for another day).

Comment: Did that, set `matches = NULL;` right after `free(matches);` now I get about `5` matches out of `28` expected and I get a `Segmentation fault`

Comment: @xtmtrx a similar stack dump (thanks for that, btw) is likely going to be required for hunting that one down. This was definitely a problem however, and not an uncommon one in reused `realloc()` algorithms.

Comment: Yes, I did that, now the `glibc` error is fixed, still getting `Segmentation fault`.

Comment: That `page[ret] = '\0';` I can even remove, is something I used to trick POSIX regex to better match because it matches (not like pcre) until firs '\0' found. (I used POSIX regex before in this code but moved to more reliable pcre)

Comment: @xtmtrx if you can ensure it works without it so much the better, because as I said, on a full-buffer it *will* invoke UB as-written.

Comment: Yes, just removed the `page[ret] = '\0';` or `page[ret] = 0;` as you suggested, still getting `Segmentation fault`, I still think is because `pcre_get_substring()` expects a string for the first argument but it gets a buffer.

Comment: @xtmtrx don't be shocked when I tell you I'm utterly unfamiliar with the api; just wringing out raw-C code over here for problems. It sounds like .n.m is familiar with it however. I would *definitely* do as alk suggests and pummel this through Valgrind. its awesome.

Comment: @xtmtrx You may find that latest addendum interesting.

Comment: Yes, but isn't `ret` identical to `sizeof(page)`? Even it isn't, just did as you said, same segfault :-|

Comment: @xtmtrx no, it isn't when the read is undersized. thats the point of `ret` in the first place, to report how much was *actually* read (or < 0 on an error condition, making it vital it be saved as a signed value, `ssize_t`). Do you have an accurate dump of the latest segfault?

Comment: Let me compile with Efence and I will generate a core dump and upload.

Comment: And/or valgrind. Either will likely tell you where you're hosing yourself.

Comment: @xtmtrx duh. check your code and read that "Update:" at the bottom of this post. was i loopy or what? =P

Comment: hey WhozCraig! tried the update just after you left for sleep, now the code doesn't seem to do anything at all, not even segfault :) I'll re-red it and try again.

Comment: @xtmtrx the mantra is pretty basic. Lemme tell you  btw, getting libpcre up and running on my mac-mavericks was ... entertaining. Alas i have no /proc fs, so I still can't run your code. ah well.

Comment: this you can run: http://pastebin.com/h0cGiagQ this works flawlessly same method as mine in question, why?

Comment: @xtmtrx yeah ok. that works. lines of `n,` where `n` is `1..8`. At least I know its running right =P

Comment: So the question is: why my code in the question above doesn't? Is the same method, only it takes the data from a process :) I was allover this all day long, I know I miss something, I can't even see straight...BTW, I owe you some beers...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47133/discussion-between-whozcraig-and-xtmtrx)

Comment: @xtmtrx ok, posted. hopefully thats it. take it for what it may be worth. To speed up implementation I just hard-coded a local pid at the start when I was debugging. You need to put back the cmd-line parsing for pid, but other that that it should work.

Comment: Amazing! Owing you those beers :)

Comment: BTW, you messed a little with the PCRE algo, I will correct it, the `vector` size is a multiple of `3` as PCRE doc says :)

Comment: If I try to match a pattern like '([0-9]{15,18})' in a string like "AAAAAAAAA960710100084303247AAAAAAAA"
I will get:
960710100084303247
60710100084303247
0710100084303247
710100084303247
instead of:
960710100084303247

Comment: @xtmtrx the vector-requires space is a multiple of three, but the actual usage is in pairs, as is the indexing. The indexing is correct as-presented. The top-third is not for you to use, but rather to provide (and if you think figuring that out wasn't easy, think again).

Comment: @xtmtrx nm. I see what you were trying to tell me. yes, I was pulling each capture rather than each full match. you're totally right on that. oks. Anyway, glad it helped. thank god for map files =P

Answer (score 3):

Besides the issues pointed out by *[WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig)*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21657878/694576):

The code defines

```
  const char *uniques[matches_len];
```

but loops its index `j` until `<uniques_len`

```
    for ( j = 0; j < uniques_len; j++)
    {
      if (!strcmp(matches[i], uniques[j]))
      {
        already_exists = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
```

So `uniques` is likely to be accessed out of bounds, provoking undefined behaviuor leading to the crash.

**Update:**

Further investgations showed this is **no** issue here, although being a dangerous construction.

---

The issue is with `matches` not pointing to proper allocated memory int this line:

```
 if (!strcmp(matches[i], uniques[j]))
```

To reveal this issue add proper memory initialisation after `realloc()`ing memory by changing this code:

```
          int count = 0;
          const char ** matches = NULL;
          [...]

                    more_matches = realloc(matches, (count+1)* sizeof(*more_matches));
                    if (more_matches!=NULL)
                    {
                        matches=more_matches;
                        matches[count++]=buff;
                    }
```

to become:

```
          size_t count = 0, count_prev = 0;
          const char ** matches = NULL;
          [...]

                    more_matches = realloc(matches, (count + 1) * sizeof(*more_matches));
                    if (more_matches != NULL)
                    {
                        memset(more_matches + count_prev, 0, (count + 1 - count_prev) * sizeof(*more_matches));
                        count_prev = count;
                        matches = more_matches;
                        matches[count++] = buff;
                    }
```

---

As a general advice: When debugging always compile with symbols on (option `-g`  to gcc), then run the code under gdb and [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org). Those two tools put the finger on most of the issues in your code.

Comment: I'm totally going to up-vote this just for the stuff I missed or haven't found before you did =P

Comment: @WhozCraig: So did I already for the NULL-pointer issue you were faster with. As well as for the `page[ret] = 0;` finding. ;-)

Comment: How you propose to correctly write the `for ( j = 0; j < uniques_len; j++)` loop so I'm not out of bounds?

Comment: @xtmtrx: I did not fully dive into the logic your code it trying to implemet, but if inside the loop the code does `uniques[j]` either do: `const char *uniques[uniques_len];` or `for ( j = 0; j < matches_len; j++)`. The size of the array shall match the index range used to address its elements.

Comment: Actually, look at that code again. the assumption is if *every* match is unique, then the most uniques you could have would be `matches_len`, which is the declared size of `uniques`. the loop is to check which ones are already present, so it should never exceed `matches_len` even when all matches are unique. iow, this may not be vital.

Comment: @WhozCraig: You talkin' to me? <tm> ;-)

Comment: @Both of you actually. Assuming *every* match is unique, I'm looking closer at the code trying to determine how `uniques_len` *exceeds* `matches_len` (it should be a given that `j` never exceeds `uniques_len`).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Valgrind told me it does. But I'll have a 2nd look. However the construct in question **is** dangerous.

Comment: I use the array to get all matches found that could be not unique then using the loop to make the output unique. Maybe was a simpler way to do it but I couldn't think of.

Comment: Well valgrind is one smart piece of work, so I err on its side of caution (or it is spewing because of the VLA being used that we see and it doesn't).

Comment: Here is a simple code for what I need to achieve, that works because the pcre matches a string: http://pastebin.com/P6eY06a1

Comment: Valgrind tells me `Use of uninitialised value of size 8` for this line `if (!strcmp(matches[i], uniques[j]))`.

Comment: Ok. i gotta call wtf on that. you're zeroing out the entire segment, then only saving *one* (the last one). its somewhat the point of realloc to *preserve* the prior content. In other words, how does losing all the prior pointers gathered in the loop fix a `strcmp` call. ?

Comment: @alk, yes, saw it, added to my code, now there's no match at all but only `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`... gdb sends me to `if (!strcmp(matches[i], uniques[j]))` as being the problem.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Phew, what a lapse. Fixed.

Comment: @xtmtrx: Fixed my proposed adjustment.

Comment: Sorry, just got back from a walk, let me check it :)

Comment: Tried your adjustment, getting segfault, and gdb says at this line `if (!strcmp(matches[i], uniques[j]))`

Comment: @xtmtrx: The segmentation violation you observe now points you to the algorithms problem; It somehow does not propberly assign values to one and/or both of the array's elements, but leaves them at the value they were initialised to, that is `NULL`. Passing `NULL` to `strcmp()` makes the code crash. Compile the sources with symbols (gcc option `-g`) and step through the code and inspect the variables using a debugger (gdb for example) to see what the code actually does.

Comment: Very strange, in a shorter script all my method works well: http://pastebin.com/P6eY06a1